# XUbuntu 18.04.3 automatic login stopped working

Tags: lightdm

I have a strange problem, we have an intel Nuc 5i3RYH which has an intel i3-5005U CPU, whcih according to intel's site has HD5500 graphics.

We where running Xubuntu 18.04.2 on this machine set to automatically login and start a web browser full screen as it is driving the information screen in our common room.

I recently upgraded to 18.04.3 and this has stopped working, but here's the weird thing, if I ssh in and restart the x server it restarts and the autologin works, which is odd.

/var/log/lightdm.log here :

```
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting Light Display Manager 1.26.0, UID=0 PID=620
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-disable-guest.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-disable-log-backup.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-greeter-wrapper.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-guest-wrapper.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xserver-command.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xubuntu-numlock.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-xubuntu.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/local/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /etc/xdg/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module local
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xremote
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module unity
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Using D-Bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Monitoring logind for seats
[+0.02s] DEBUG: New seat added from logind: seat0
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Loading properties from config section Seat:*
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating user session
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Loading users from org.freedesktop.Accounts
[+0.03s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1000 added
[+0.14s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1001 added
[+0.16s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating display server of type x
[+0.18s] DEBUG: Quitting Plymouth
[+0.19s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
[+0.19s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting local X display on VT 7
[+0.19s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
[+0.19s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Writing X server authority to /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+0.19s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Launching X Server
[+0.19s] DEBUG: Launching process 701: /usr/bin/X -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
[+0.19s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Waiting for ready signal from X server :0
[+0.19s] DEBUG: Acquired bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.19s] DEBUG: Registering seat with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
[+0.73s] DEBUG: Process 701 terminated with signal 6
[+0.73s] DEBUG: XServer 0: X server stopped
[+0.73s] DEBUG: Releasing VT 7
[+0.73s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Removing X server authority /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+0.73s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server stopped
[+0.73s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping session
[+0.73s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session stopped
[+0.73s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping display server, no sessions require it
[+0.73s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Active display server stopped, starting greeter
[+0.73s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating greeter session
[+0.73s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating display server of type x
[+0.73s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
[+0.73s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting local X display on VT 7
[+0.73s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
[+0.73s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Writing X server authority to /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+0.73s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Launching X Server
[+0.73s] DEBUG: Launching process 767: /usr/bin/X -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
[+0.73s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Waiting for ready signal from X server :0
[+1.79s] DEBUG: Got signal 10 from process 767
[+1.79s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Got signal from X server :0
[+1.79s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Connecting to XServer :0
[+1.82s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server ready, starting session authentication
[+1.82s] DEBUG: Session pid=813: Started with service 'lightdm-greeter', username 'lightdm'
[+1.83s] DEBUG: Session pid=813: Authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+1.83s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session authenticated, running command
[+1.83s] DEBUG: Launching process 816: xubuntu-numlockx
[+1.91s] DEBUG: Process 816 exited with return value 0
[+1.91s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Exit status of xubuntu-numlockx: 0
[+1.91s] DEBUG: Session pid=813: Running command /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-greeter-session /usr/sbin/lightdm-gtk-greeter
[+1.91s] DEBUG: Creating shared data directory /var/lib/lightdm-data/lightdm
[+1.91s] DEBUG: Session pid=813: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/seat0-greeter.log
[+1.99s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+1.99s] DEBUG: Activating login1 session c1
[+1.99s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to c1
[+1.99s] DEBUG: Session c1 is already active
[+2.14s] DEBUG: Greeter connected version=1.26.0 api=1 resettable=false
[+2.42s] DEBUG: Greeter start authentication for itadmin
[+2.42s] DEBUG: Session pid=893: Started with service 'lightdm', username 'itadmin'
[+2.43s] DEBUG: Session pid=893: Got 1 message(s) from PAM
[+2.43s] DEBUG: Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
```

/var/log/x-0.log

```
X.Org X Server 1.20.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-148-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux crdisplay 5.0.0-31-generic #33~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 10:20:39 UTC 2019 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-31-generic root=UUID=7ba381e6-d61f-489f-ae9c-a7e462ea269c ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
Build Date: 02 May 2019  08:06:54AM
xorg-server-hwe-18.04 2:1.20.4-1ubuntu3~18.04.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Oct  7 15:23:36 2019
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
vesa: Ignoring device with a bound kernel driver
vesa: Ignoring device with a bound kernel driver
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.

X.Org X Server 1.20.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-148-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux crdisplay 5.0.0-31-generic #33~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 10:20:39 UTC 2019 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-31-generic root=UUID=7ba381e6-d61f-489f-ae9c-a7e462ea269c ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
Build Date: 02 May 2019  08:06:54AM
xorg-server-hwe-18.04 2:1.20.4-1ubuntu3~18.04.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Oct  7 15:23:37 2019
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(II) modeset(0): Initializing kms color map for depth 24, 8 bpc.
```

Anyone have any clues as to what is going on here ?

Cheers.

Phill.

Comment: I have solved this now, it turned out for some reason that during the upgrade from 18.04.2 to .3 Hardware Enablement Stack (hwe) had not been updated, updating that resolved the lightdm login issue.